# Getting data from a timeframe based on a date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get data from a 30 day timeframe from before and after a notification has been sent. I've tried the below query but it doesn't completely give me what I want. The created_at field is a date at which a message has been sent. I'm trying to establish a correlation between the date a message has been sent and the field epaper_opens. To this end I'm looking at 30 day intervals before and after the created_at event occurs.

```
SELECT state,
       epaper_opens,
       CAST(created_at AS date) AS Date,
       COUNT(created_at) AS Sent

FROM analytics.fct_notifications

LEFT JOIN analytics.fcts_customer_activity_agg
  ON fct_notifications.customer_id = fcts_customer_activity_agg.subscription_id

WHERE DATE > DATE_SUB(CAST(created_at AS date), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  AND DATE < DATE_ADD(CAST(created_at AS date), INTERVAL 30 DAY)

GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: Please explain what the issue is.  Your question is quite unclear.   Sample data and desired results would really help, as would knowing where the columns are coming from.

Comment: It's good programming practice to always qualify all columns when several tables are involved. I.e. `table_name.column_name` instead of just `column_name`.

Comment: Tip: Table aliases make life easier! E.g. `FROM analytics.fct_notifications AS n ... ON n.customer_id = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with what @Gordon Linoff said, it would be helpful to know your tables structure, the obtained results and the desired results.

I recreated a similar scenario in BQ using the same WHERE clause you used and it works well, except that the interval limits are not inclusive (since you're using the < and > operators instead of <= and >=), so you're actually getting results from 29 days before and 29 days after the created_at date; would that be what you're referring to when you say that your query is not giving you all the results that you want?

If that is the case you could either try to use the mentioned operators:

```
WHERE DATE >= DATE_SUB(CAST(created_at AS date), INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  AND DATE <= DATE_ADD(CAST(created_at AS date), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

or you might as well could use the [BETWEEN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#comparison_operators) operator which has inclusive limits:

```
WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CAST(created_at AS date), INTERVAL 30 DAY)

  AND DATE_ADD(CAST(created_at AS date), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```